# Is overriding static field with static block bad practice?

Tags: java, static, subclassing

I want to create data structures to capture the following ideas:

In a game, I want to have a generic `Skill` class that captures general information like skill id, cool down time, mana cost, etc.

Then I want to have specific skills that define actual interaction and behaviours. So these would all extend from base class `Skill`.

Finally, each player will have instances of these specific skills, so I can check each player's skill status, whether a player used it recently, etc.

So I have an abstract superclass `Skill` that defines some static variables, which all skills have in common, and then for each individual skill that extends `Skill`, I use a static block to reassign the static variables. So I have the following pattern:

```
class A {
    static int x = 0;
}

class B extends A {
    static {
        x = 1;
    }
}

...

// in a method
A b = new B();
System.out.println(b.x);
```

The above prints 1, which is exactly the behaviour I want. My only problem is that the system complains about I'm accessing static variable in a non-static way. But of course I can't access it in that way, because I only want to treat the skill as `Skill` without knowing exactly which subclass it is. So I have to suppress the warning every time I do this, which leads me to think whether there is a better/neater design pattern here.

I have thought about making the variables in question non-static, but because they should be static across *all* instances of the specific skill, I feel like it should be a static variable...

Comment: If Each Skill subclass has its own value of x, then you should have a static `x` field in every subclass. As is, loading the class B will set A.x to 1. Make your x variables final. If you want to access a variable value in a polymorphic way, then you should have a non-static `getX()` method in each class. Whether it returns always the same constant value or not is an implementation detail.

Comment: The problem is... you do not change all instances of the specific skill, but rather all instances of all skills, since you change the attribute in class `A` (which I assume is your `AbstractSkill` class). Therefore `x` is `1` for all classes that extend `A`. I would tend to use an Interface for your skills, defining the needed methods and hide the implementation details. You can have some kind of `public int getX()` and not care about the implementation.

Comment: This is just a complete aside, but I would separate the two things completely: I'd have a `SkillInfo` class/enum, which contains all the generic information about a skill (name, description, pre-requisites, etc.), skills would not extend this, just have an instance each. And you can create separate classes implementing skill behaviours, one for each skill.

Comment: It seems that the code doesn't even work! Well, since Java does not allow overriding static methods, I suppose there is no way to make these shared variables static...

Answer (score 3):

You should generally avoid such use of global state. If you know for sure that the field `x` will be shared across *all* instances of *all* subtypes of the base class, then the correct place to put such a field is probably somewhere other than the base class. It may be in some other configuration object.

But even with your current configuration, it just does't make sense since any subclass that modifies the static variable will make the variable visible to all classes. If subclass `B` changes `x` to 1, then subclass `C` changes it to 2, the new value would be visible to `B` as well.

I think that the way you described in the question, every subclass should have its own separate static field. And in the abstract base class, you can define a method to be implemented by each subclass in order to access each field:

```
abstract class A {

    public abstract int getX();
}

class B extends A {
    public static int x = 1;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}

class C extends A {
    public static int x = 2;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems I should have tested it more extensively. However, how would you model it? I think my problem is I want declare an abstract method/field that I feel should also be static, in the sense that in the subclass the value is constant across all instances.

Comment: There is no such thing as abstract field, and abstract methods cannot be static. I think that the way you described in the question, every subclass should have its own separate static field.

Comment: But that way I lose the abstraction. I cannot, for example, iterate through a list of `Skill`s, which I know of which each has a static variable called `foo`, without knowing exactly what subclass each instance is. I also do not wish to use reflection.

Comment: As mentioned in one of the other comments, you can have an abstract method defined in the base class, which every subclass can implement to return that static field. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by some answers and comments, your approach won't work the way you want because every static block changes the static variable for all classes extending `A`.

Use an interface and instance methods instead:

```
public interface A {
    int getX();
}
```

-

```
public class B implements A {

    private static final int X = 1;

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return X;
    }
}
```

-

```
A myInstance = new B();
System.out.println(myInstance.getX()); // prints "1"
```

Comment: However, since the value will be constant across all instances of B, I feel like it is more elegant to have it as a static method that A knows...which I guess is really not supported in Java...

Comment: There will only be one static instance of X across all instances of B. But as you guessed correctly there is no way to use a static field or method defined in A to do what you want.